# LEFT JOIN 2 tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, left-join

I got 2 tables as below

The 1st table, Segment_info

| BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | SSRCode | SSRCreatedUTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | WCI | 2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | MCI | 2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | PB20 | 2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | AB25 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | WCI | 2023-04-07 14:53:00.407000 UTC |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | MCI | 2023-04-07 12:20:07.547000 UTC |

The 2nd table, Baggage_Info

| SegmentID | BaggageID | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 371 | 1350 | 20 |
| 371 | 1351 | 28 |
| 372 | 1230 | 8 |
| 372 | 1231 | 24 |
| 372 | 1232 | 15 |

---

I want to map Baggage_Info to Segment_info based on the following rules.

1. When there are SSRCode equals to either ‘AB20’, ‘AB25’, ‘AB30’ or ‘AB40’, maps the baggage_info with the same SegmentID first
2. If there are no SSRCode equals to either ‘AB20’, ‘AB25’, ‘AB30’ or ‘AB40’,  but either ‘PB20’, ‘PB25’, ‘PB30’ or ‘PB40’ are shown, maps the baggage_info to the earliest SSRCreatedUTC with the same SegmentID
3. If the above 2 conditions do not meet and there are SSRCode equals to either ‘WCI’ or ‘MCI’, maps the baggage_info to the earliest SSRCreatedUTC with the same SegmentID

---

The expected result:

| BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | SSRCode | SSRCreatedUTC | BaggageID | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | WCI | 2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | MCI | 2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | PB20 | 2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | AB25 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC | 1350 | 20 |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | AB25 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC | 1351 | 28 |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | WCI | 2023-04-07 14:53:00.407000 UTC | NULL | NULL |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | MCI | 2023-04-07 12:20:07.547000 UTC | 1230 | 8 |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | MCI | 2023-04-07 12:20:07.547000 UTC | 1231 | 24 |
| 124 | 372 | 261 | MCI | 2023-04-07 12:20:07.547000 UTC | 1232 | 15 |

Right now I am using the following sql

```
WITH 

segment_info AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SegmentID ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN SSRCode IN ('AB20', 'AB25', 'AB30', 'AB40') THEN 1
      WHEN SSRCode IN ('PB20', 'PB25', 'PB30', 'PB40') THEN 2  
      WHEN SSRCode IN ('WCI', 'MCI') THEN 3
      ELSE 4 END,
      SSRCreatedUTC ASC
    ) AS rn
  FROM
    `Segment_info`
),

final_output AS (SELECT

    SI.BookingID,
    SI.SegmentID,
    SI.PassengerID,

    SI.SSRCode,
    SI.SSRCreatedUTC,

    BI.BaggageID,
    BI.Weight
FROM
  segment_info SI
LEFT JOIN
  `Baggage_Info` BI ON SI.SegmentID = BI.SegmentID
WHERE
  SI.rn = 1)

SELECT * FROM final_output
```

However, it does not give me the desired result
Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe what on the output is not archived? I guess, you want to include the complete table `Segment_info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter the best dataset using `WHERE Si.rn=1`. However, you do not want to filter but, restrict the join. Therefore, replace the `WHERE` by an `AND`.

I added `raw_input_line_number`, because you sorted the wished results in your example. and `rn` to the output.

```sql
With Segment_info_raw as 
( Select BookingID,BookingID+248 SegmentID, BookingID*10-979 PassengerID,SSRCode, SSRCreatedUTC,
row_number() over () as raw_input_line_number,
from (  
   select 123 BookingID, timestamp "2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC" SSRCreatedUTC,"WCI" SSRCode
union all select 123, timestamp "2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC", "MCI"
union all select 123, timestamp "2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC", "PB20"
union all select 123, timestamp "2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC", "AB25"
union all select 124, timestamp "2023-04-07 14:53:00.407000 UTC", "WCI"
union all select 124, timestamp "2023-04-07 12:20:07.547000 UTC", "MCI"
)
),
Baggage_Info as 
(
Select  371 SegmentID,  1350    BaggageID,  20 Weight
union all Select    371 ,   1351    ,   28
union all Select    372 ,   1230    ,   8
union all Select    372 ,   1231    ,   24
union all Select    372 ,   1232    ,   15
),


segment_info AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SegmentID ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN SSRCode IN ('AB20', 'AB25', 'AB30', 'AB40') THEN 1
      WHEN SSRCode IN ('PB20', 'PB25', 'PB30', 'PB40') THEN 2  
      WHEN SSRCode IN ('WCI', 'MCI') THEN 3
      ELSE 4 END,
      SSRCreatedUTC ASC
    ) AS rn
  FROM
    `Segment_info_raw`
),

final_output AS (SELECT

    SI.BookingID,
    SI.SegmentID,
    SI.PassengerID,

    SI.SSRCode,
    SI.SSRCreatedUTC,

    BI.BaggageID,
    BI.Weight,
    rn,
    raw_input_line_number

FROM
  segment_info SI
LEFT JOIN
  `Baggage_Info` BI ON SI.SegmentID = BI.SegmentID
# WHERE SI.rn = 1 # This would filter the result that only the best matching lines are shown
AND   SI.rn = 1  # This restricts the join to the best matching, but does not do a filter on the first table to display
)

SELECT * FROM final_output
order by raw_input_line_number
```